# push notification plugin error while working with pushwoosh and phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, pushwoosh

i have followed all the steps to add pushwoosh to my android project in phonegap, all is well only problem i am getting is when i have added this plugin to my src/com folder, it shows error in PushNotifications.java file right after refreshing in eclipse, it shows error as The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved

Can anyone please help me with this problem..

thanks
- Swan

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have not enough reputation to leave a comment! Anyway, I had issues setting up push notification on pushwosh and phonegap too.

The documentation is weak/outdated on both github and pushwooshmain thing to do is to follow the instructions as written and add   to your config.xml file

I have some notes in [here](http://vicrandom.blogspot.ca/2014/01/push-notification-phonegap-30-with.html)